# How to add temporary columns to list of columns in the select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, multiple-columns

I have written the following code as shown below:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ColumnList nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @SampleTable nvarchar(max);

SET @SampleTable = 'dbo.CourseType' --HERE I'LL BE GIVING LIST OF TABLES

SELECT
    @ColumnList = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT N', ' + QOUTENAME(c.name)
                                 FROM sys.columns c
                                 INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
                                 WHERE o.name = @SampleTable 
                                   AND c.name NOT IN ('ID', 'Number')
                                 ORDER BY c.column_id 
                                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')) 

SELECT @ColumnList
```

From this script I'll get the list of all columns except columns `ID`, `Number`. Now what I want to do is that read this list of columns i.e `[Name], [Description], [SortOrder], [BusinessName], [Obsolete]` with some temporary columns listed below:

```
NULL AS EntityID,
NULL AS ModifiedBy,
NULL AS CreatedBy
```

The query result should look like this:

```
Name         Description                        SortOrder   BusinessMeaningName         Obsolete   EntityID    ModifiedBy    CreatedBy
Inviern      Cursos de Invierno de Pregrado         1       AcademicPeriodType.Invierno    0         NULL       NULL          NULL
Lectivo      Cursos Lectivos de Pregrado            0       AcademicPeriodType.Lectivo     0         NULL       NULL          NULL
Verano       Cursos de Verano de Pregrado           1       AcademicPeriodType.Verano      0         NULL       NULL          NULL
```

I know that I can do this directly by just selecting the names of columns with the temporary columns for one or two tables. But i have to do this for a large bunch of tables. I cant figure out a way to do this.

Now I don't know how to add `EntityID, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy` in the select statement. I've tried to do something like this.

```
SET @SQL = 'SELET '
            + @ColumnList
            + ' FROM ' + @SampleTable;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the additional columns in your dynamic statement.

```sql
--Dynamic object should be declared like this
DECLARE @SampleSchema sysname = N'dbo',
        @SampleTable sysname = N'CourseType';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           @ColumnList +
           N', NULL AS EntityID, NULL AS ModifiedBy, NULL AS CreatedBy' +
           N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SampleSchema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@SampleTable) + N';';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Also, a object's name can only be 255 characters long, so don't use a `nvarchar(MAX)` for its datatype. Declare `@SampleTable` as a `sysname`.

Comment: Thanks! Will implement your advice as well.

Comment: Just noticed you use set the value of `@SampleTable` to `'dbo.CourseType'`. the schema and table should be different parameters, will adjsut my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks once again. I've just started using dynamic sql. So going through lots of trials and runs.

Comment: A little bit of shameless self promotion for you then, @astroluv : [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Now i want to give this @SQL as an input for another table? How can i do that? Because i can not give this "EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;" as SLEECT Statement  for the insert statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, @astroluv , but sounds like you're asking a new question, so should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Note that nulls pulled from thin air are `int` missing values. If you want a different data type you can use `Cast( NULL as NVarChar(50) ) as ModifiedBy` to provide a more suitable type.